# Convergence of improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1/3}} dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, improper-integrals

I first tried to separate the integral from 0 to 1 and 1 to $\infty$ but it didn't work because the upper bound is divergent. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})}$$

Comment: duplicate for sure

Comment: i´m supposed to use Calculus I to solve the problem

Comment: There's no "divergent upper bound", the integral is obviously convergent by Dirichlet's criterion, and integration by parts works. Advice: learn theory and practice algebra/calculus, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin x}{x^{1/3}}dx&=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\sin x}{x^{1/3}}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin x}{x^{1/3}}dx,
\end{align*}
where $\left|\dfrac{\sin x}{x^{1/3}}\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{x^{1/3}}$ on $[0,1]$ and hence the first improper integral converges absolutely.

For the second improper integral, note that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin x}{x^{1/3}}dx&=-\dfrac{\cos x}{x^{1/3}}\bigg|_{x=1}^{x=\infty}-\dfrac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos x}{x^{4/3}}dx\\
&=\cos 1-\dfrac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos x}{x^{4/3}}dx,
\end{align*}
and $\left|\dfrac{\cos x}{x^{4/3}}\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{x^{4/3}}$ on $[1,\infty)$ and hence $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos x}{x^{4/3}}dx$ converges absolutely.